# Delete rows from table by class name

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to delete  rows from table by class name:

```
var tr = document.getElementsByClassName('edited');
var table = document.getElementById('messagebox');

for(var i = 0; i < tr.length ; i++){
    table.deleteRow(tr[i].rowIndex);
}
```

But not all removed

Comment: Can you share your html? Or something else to show which ones are not removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having more info (html example, etc.), I'd say the issue is likely to be that you are removing rows from the front of the list.

Say you have rows 2, 4, and 6 edited.  When you remove row 2, row 4 becomes row 3 and row 6 becomes row 5, so the next row you remove (originally 4) is actually 5), etc.

Use `for(var i = tr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){`

Comment: Its a solution for my problem, but why i cant get text from cell?
script.js:144 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cells' of undefined when 

tr[j].cells[3].innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

```
var tr = document.getElementsByClassName('edited');
var table = document.getElementById('messagebox');
```

You used live collection, it automatically updated when you doing something with your elements, but you need to use other things.

```
elem.querySelectorAll(css)
```

It will return find elements.

```
elem.querySelector(css)
```

It will return only first find element.