# how to filter an array based on getElementByClassName

Tags: javascript

```
let tableData = Array.from(
      domUpperTable.getElementsByClassName('mat-row')
    );
```

// tableData is as below

```
[tr.mat-row.cdk-row.ng-tns-c398-0.ng-star-inserted, 
tr.mat-row.cdk-row.example-detail-row.ng-tns-c398-0.ng-star-inserted, 
tr.mat-row.cdk-row.ng-tns-c398-0.ng-star-inserted, 
tr.mat-row.cdk-row.example-detail-row.ng-tns-c398-0.ng-star-inserted]
```

I am trying to do a forEach on the tableData but i want to remove the rows 1 and 3 which contain classname as example-detail-row.

Can you suggest me on how to do that ?

Comment: I would change your query to look for the class name "example-detail-row", then iterate over the result and use `element.parentNode.removeChild(element)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete rows from table by class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36703232/delete-rows-from-table-by-class-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using a CSS selector when creating the original `tableData`.

```
let tableData = domUpperTable.querySelectorAll(".mat-row:not(.example-detail-row)");
```

If you want to keep the complete array, you can use `.classList.includes()` in a `filter()` call.

```
filteredTableData = tableData.filter(el => !el.classList.includes("example-detail-row"));
```